# Modal Window with HTML5 and css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I'm using this popup for Modal Windows with html5 and css3

Htlml:

```
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>Modal Box</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
}
```

The question is:
When a video is playing inside the window and I close it, the video is not stopping, and I can still hear the sound in the background. Is there a way to force reset or stop the video?

Comment: what kind of video player do you use ?

Comment: working snippet would be useful.

Comment: can you share javascript or jquery functions you are using to start video?
you can try to call 
$('#playerID').get(0).stopVideo();
after closing your model

Comment: this player is not required any JS it's CSS3 and HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this by jQuery function. check the [fidde link](https://jsfiddle.net/Shanthece/79j69eh9/65/)

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#vid")[0].pause();
};

function hidevideo() {
    document.getElementById("openModal").style.display = "none";
    $("#vid")[0].pause();
};

function openvideo() {
    document.getElementById("openModal").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#vid")[0].play();
    }, 200);
    $("#vid")[0].play();
};
```

Html:

```
<a onclick="openvideo();">Open Modal</a>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="javascript;" title="Close" class="close" onclick="hidevideo()">X</a>
    <h2>Modal Box</h2>
    <video autoplay="autoplay" id="vid" preload="none" controls>
      <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gaurav answered your question, am just expanding that exactly

Comment: i replaced my code with yours but it's still not working, actually your code autoplay the video when page load and i can't see the popup when i tried to click on Open Modal

Comment: nope it forces to pause the video when dom ready [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Shanthece/79j69eh9/69/) ,you can add css to overlay and video you want